# What does '0' mean in C?

Tags: c, data-structures

In the code for evaluating postfix expression, it's written that for passing a character as an integer we write it as `character - '0'`. What is the significance of this?

Comment: You really need to spend hours to read some good C programming books. Don't expect us to teach you it here.

Answer (score 6):

This is because `charater - '0'` gives the integer value of the character.
C standar states that:

#### C11 5.2.1 3:

> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after `0` in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

Using the fact stated above, the integer value of a character between `0` to `9` can be calculated by the above expression.

```
char character = '5';
int val = character - '0';
```

Now if `48` is the code for `0` then

```
'5' - '0' = 53 - 48 = 5   //
```

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Such character sets are not permitted in C. C 2011 5.2.1 3 requires that the digits be consecutive.

Comment: @EricPostpischil; True. I just consider that to explain the arithmetic.

Answer (score 5):

That is a quick way for converting a digit character to number. It is based on the fact that characters are encoded as numbers and the C standard requirement that characters representing digits must be consecutive (see @EricPostpischil's comment below).

So if 48 is the code corresponding to `'0'`, then 49 will be `'1'` and so on. Thus, you can convert `'1'` (character) to `1` (integer) by `'1' - '0' = 49 - 48 = 1`.

Comment: The fact that the digit characters are consecutive is not an assumption; it is an explicit requirement of the C standard, per C 2011 5.2.1 3: “In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil; Thanks for the standard. Quoting that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks, I was not aware of that.